# LightBox gallery not working

Tags: jquery, css, gallery, lightbox

i am trying to make a lightbox gallery . when i click first image , it show the content normal, even i close and opne , it work fine.
when i come to image two , if i click it , it show me the lightbox for the first image.

can any one help me please
http://jsfiddle.net/wwavyh0y/2/

```js
/* Slideshow + Lightbox */

$(document).ready(function() {

 // Redéfinition de styles
 $(".slideshow").css("position","relative");
 $(".slideshow img").css("position","absolute");
 $(".slideshow img:gt(0)").hide();
 
 // Ajout des liens
 $(".slideshow").append("<p><a href=\"#\" class=\"prev\">previouse</a> | <a href=\"#\" class=\"next\">Next</a></p>");
 $(".slideshow p").css("padding-top","340px");
 
 // Clic sur le lien suivant
 $(".slideshow a.next").click(function() {
  var $img_suivante = $(".slideshow img:visible").next("img");
  if($img_suivante.length<1) $img_suivante = $(".slideshow img:first");
  $(".slideshow img:visible").fadeOut();
  $img_suivante.fadeIn();
 });
 
 // Clic sur le lien précédent
 $(".slideshow a.prev").click(function() {
  var $img_precedente = $(".slideshow img:visible").prev("img");
  if($img_precedente.length<1) $img_precedente = $(".slideshow img:last");
  $(".slideshow img:visible").fadeOut();
  $img_precedente.fadeIn(); 
 });
 
 // Lightbox

 
 
 $(".dolightbox").click(openlight);
 
 // Modification dynamique de la page et des styles
 function openlight() {
  var item=$(this).parent().attr("id");
  alert(item);
  $("#"+item).children(".work-item-desc-slide").css("display","block");
  $("body").append("<div id=\"zone\"></div>");
  $("body").prepend("<div id=\"cache\"></div>");
  $("#cache").css({
   "width":"100%",
   "height":"100%",
   "background":"#1d2f3e",
   "z-index":"10",
   "position":"absolute",
   "top":"0",
   "left":"0"
  });
  

  $(".work-item-desc-slide").after("<span class='marquage'></span>");
  $("#zone").prepend("<p style=\"text-align:right;margin:0\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"close\">Close</a></p>");
  $("#zone a").click(closelight);
  $("#"+item+" .work-item-desc-slide").appendTo("#zone");
 }

 
 // Fermer la lightbox
 function closelight() {
  // On rétablit les éléments à leur position originale dans le flux
  $(".work-item-desc-slide").appendTo(".marquage");
  $("#zone, #cache").remove();
 }
 

});
```

```css
body {
 background: #1C1C1C;
 color: #444;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#wrap img {
    width:100px;
    height : 100px;
}

.work-item-desc-slide a,.close a {
 color: rgba(15,159,180,1);
 text-decoration: none;
}


div#wrap {
 position:relative;
 margin:auto;
 color: #d5d5d5;
 width: 640px;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:200px;
}
.item{
 margin: 30px;
}
.marquage {
 display: none;
}
#zone {
 width: 90%;
 height: 90%;
 background-color: #314252;
 z-index: 20;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 10px;
 left: 5%;
 top: 4%;
}
.work-item-desc-slide {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.slideshow img {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
.slideshow,.work-item-info-slide{
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 -o-box-sizing:border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 margin: 0 auto;
 float: left;
}
.work-item-info-slide h2{
 color: rgba(201,225,193,0.9);
}
.work-item-info-slide h1 {
 color: rgba(15,159,180,1);
}
.work-tem-info-hr {
 border: none;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: rgba(201,225,193,0.13);
 width: 70%;
 position: relative;
 left: -77px;
}
.work-item-info-slide p{
 color: #f9f9f9;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.work-item-info-slide ul{
 list-style: none;
 color: #f9f9f9;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.work-item-info-slide ul li {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.work-item-info-slide ul li span{
 background-color: rgba(15,159,180,0.4);
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding: 5px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="wrap">
  <div id="item1">
   <img src="http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg" alt="first item" class="dolightbox"/>
   <div class="work-item-desc-slide">
    <div class="slideshow">
     <img src="http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg" alt="first item slide" />
     <img src="http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/12/1/sunset-mcgary-background-back-screensavers-seconds-start-thank-click-127921.jpg" alt="Calamar" />
     
    </div><!-- end slidshow-->

    <div class="work-item-info-slide">
     <h1>Company Name</h1>
     <hr class="work-tem-info-hr">
     <h2>About The Client</h2>
     <p>
      eap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was populari
     </p>
     <h2> Services Provided</h2>
     <ul class="services-provided">
      <li><span>1</span> Service 1</li>
      <li><span>2</span> Service 2</li>
      <li><span>3</span> Service 3</li>
     </ul>
     <hr class="work-tem-info-hr">
     <a href="Index.html">Check out the WebSite</a>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
   </div>
   
  </div><!-- end item1-->



 
  <div  id="item2">
   <img src="http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2012/208/7/b/every_child_is_an_artist__the_problem_is_how_to_re_by_streetartsavemylife-d58uv1d.jpg" alt="item 2" class="dolightbox"/>
   <div class="work-item-desc-slide">
    <div class="slideshow">
     <img src="http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2012/208/7/b/every_child_is_an_artist__the_problem_is_how_to_re_by_streetartsavemylife-d58uv1d.jpg" alt="Musiciens" />
     <img src="http://www.scottchristensen.com.au/Images/artist-profile-picture.jpg" alt="Calamar" />
    </div>
    <div class="work-item-info-slide">
     <h1>Company Name 2</h1>
     <hr class="work-tem-info-hr">
     <h2>About The Client 2</h2>
     <p>
      eap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was populari
     </p>
     <h2> Services Provided</h2>
     <ul class="services-provided">
      <li><span>1</span> Service 1</li>
      <li><span>2</span> Service 2</li>
      <li><span>3</span> Service 3</li>
     </ul>
     <hr class="work-tem-info-hr">
     <a href="Index.html">Check out the WebSite</a>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- end item1-->
 </div>
```